# Synchronise Apache logout with django logout

Tags: python, django, apache, authentication, authorization

I have a site with static elements like images. I wanted to protect them (so that you cannot access them directly using a hotlink). For this purpose I used the part "Authentication with mod_wsgi" from the Django documentation:
[Authentication with mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/apache-auth/)

I don't like that fact that the user has to log in twice (one time Django auth and then Apache auth when there is an image on the page) but it's not the main issue (if you know how to handle this it would also be nice)

My main problem is that after I log out I still can access the protected image. I know that this is because the fact that Apache uses only Djangos `check_password` method but maybe there is a way to synchronise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at Apache 'X-SENDFILE' header: https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

It allow Django to check if your user can access it and if he the access is granted the static file is then served by Apache.

With this solution your user don't have to log twice and you can have any kind of control your want !

I wrote a blog post about it [here](https://b0uh.github.io/protect-django-media-files-per-user-basis-with-nginx.html) with nginx, but it work the same way :)

Comment: Thanks very much! Looks promising, I will give it a try :)! So I would only need to change the nginx header `X-Accel-Redirect` to the Apache `X-SENDFILE` header?

Comment: Exactly, `X-Sendfile` is the header used by the apache module and it works the same way as for nginx :)